# Automatic page return link in Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, button

I would like to find a proper way to add a cancel close button next to the submit button on forms with Symfony 5.
Based on my research on Internet, I found various ways :

- add the button on the twig template with the submit_widget blog. It works, but I'm not able to change the route as I can't transfert any variables from the Controller.
- add a simple like with `href="javascript:history.go(-1)"`. Efficient but ugly !
- add an other submit button with an formnovalidate attribute based on [that post](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#client-side-html-validation) and [that post](https://www.strangebuzz.com/en/blog/disable-the-html5-validation-of-all-your-symfony-forms-with-a-feature-flag). But I seems that this function is longer working in Symfony 5.

I can't figure out that this type of feature is not possible on a framework.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to manually create the button in the Twig view and set up it's href accordingly.

Eg. if you are on the `blog_posts_edit` page, create a link to the `block_posts_index` page (mutatis mutandis):

```
<a href="{{ path('blog_posts_index') }}">
    Return to the list
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
That's what I was thinking first. But in my case, the template is common to all the forms of my website. So the "parent" page is not always the same. I didn't find a way to transfert variables to the form variable that Twig use for the template.

Comment: If your route names are predictive you could generate the return route dynamically. If not you could extract the button to a Twig macro to ease the use of generating the html – the route name would still be required though. Not too many options here – personally I would never use the `history.back(1)` js approach.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a solution based on the advice of emix.

So yes, obviously, let's forget the js option.

To access to a variable inside the twig form template, I simply pass a variable 'route_back' in the Controller :

```
$view = $form->createView();
$view->vars['route_back']='account';
return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
    'form' => $view
]);
```

And then, add dynamically insert the link in the twig form template :

```
{%- block form_end -%}
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a class="btn-secondary btn w-75" href="{{ path(route_back) }}">{% trans %}Cancel{% endtrans %}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-left">
            <button type="submit" id="account_save" name="account[save]" class="btn-primary btn w-75">{% trans %}Save{% endtrans %}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
{%- endblock form_end -%}
```

On the type form, I've removed of course the submit button as recommended in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#add-form-buttons-in-templates) :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
    ;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn’t be done this way. Later today I’ll give you an example how to do this correctly using form extensions. You are not supposed to mess with the view vars anywhere outside of the form itself.